# Mocha.js: to run "after" hook even if test suit fails

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Is it possible to run  "after" hook even if one of tests (suite) fails?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, both `after` and `afterEach` hooks should be run when a test fails.

See these github issues for related discussions and changes: [#94](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/issues/94), [#125](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/issues/125), [#143](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/issues/143), [#690](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/issues/690).

Here is an example to prove my claim:

```
describe('test', function() {
  after(function() { console.log('after'); });
  afterEach(function() { console.log('afterEach'); });

  it('fails sync', function(done) {
    after(function() { console.log('inner after 1'); });
    throw new Error('failed');
  });

  it('fails async', function(done) {
    after(function() { console.log('inner after 2'); });
    process.nextTick(function() {
      throw new Error('failed');
    });
  });
});
```

which produces the following output with mocha 1.1.12:

```
  ․afterEach
․afterEach
after
inner after 1
inner after 2


  0 passing (5 ms)
  2 failing

1) test fails sync:
 Error: failed
  at Context.<anonymous> (/private/tmp/so/test/main.js:7:11)
  at Test.Runnable.run (/private/tmp/so/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:194:15)
  at Runner.runTest (/private/tmp/so/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:355:10)
  at /private/tmp/so/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:401:12
  at next (/private/tmp/so/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:281:14)
  at /private/tmp/so/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:290:7
  at next (/private/tmp/so/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:234:23)
  at Object._onImmediate (/private/tmp/so/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:258:5)
  at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:330:15)

2) test fails async:
 Error: failed
  at /private/tmp/so/test/main.js:13:12
  at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```